# Explore convergence of $\sum_{n=3}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n\ln n(\ln\ln n)^\alpha}$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, sequences-and-series

Explore convergence of  $\sum_{n=3}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n\ln n(\ln \ln n)^\alpha}$

Tried to use Cauchy integral test,so we need to find

$$\int_{3}^\infty\frac{dx}{x\ln x(\ln \ln x)^\alpha}=\int_{\ln 3}^{\infty}\frac{dz}{z(\ln z)^\alpha}= \int_{\ln (\ln 3)}^{\infty}\frac{du}{(u^\alpha)}$$

and stuck here. How continue from here?

I know that $\displaystyle\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n^\alpha}$ converges when $\alpha>1$ and diverges when $\alpha\leq1$

but here we start sum from $\ln (\ln 3)$ not-natural number can we say same thing here and why if we can?

Comment: Please ue `\ln` $\ln$ not `ln` $ln$

Comment: Do you want to find such $\alpha$ that there's convergence or do you want to find the sum?

Comment: @BotnakovN. Exercise says find where it is divergent and where is conergent.

Comment: @unit1991 so it's better to reformulate your question.

Comment: @BotnakovN. Done!

Answer (score 1):

**HINT:**

Note that we have for $\alpha\ne 1$

$$\int_3^\infty \frac{1}{x\log(x) \left(\log(\log(x))\right)^\alpha}\,dx=\left.\left(\frac1{(1-\alpha)\left(\log(\log(x))\right)^{\alpha-1}}\right)\right|_3^\infty$$

If $\alpha=1$, then we have

$$\int_3^\infty \frac{1}{x\log(x)\log(\log(x))}\,dx=\left.\left(\frac1{\log(\log(\log(x)))}\right)\right|_3^\infty$$

Can you finish now?

Comment: @unit1991 If you got stuck while integrating $\int \frac{du}{u^{\alpha}}$ and if "note that the equality $$\int_3^\infty \frac{1}{x\log(x) \left(\log(\log(x))\right)^\alpha}\,dx=\left.\left(\frac1{(1-\alpha)\left(\log(\log(x))\right)^{\alpha-1}}\right)\right|_3^\infty$$ holds true" is a better hint, then the hint about integrating  $\int \frac{du}{u^{\alpha}}$, it will be really surprising))

Answer (score 0):

You already almost solved the problem.

If $\alpha \ne 1$ we have
$$\int_{\ln (\ln 3)}^{\infty}\frac{du}{(u^\alpha)} = \int_{\ln (\ln 3)}^{\infty} u^{-\alpha} du = \frac{u^{-\alpha+1}}{-\alpha+1}  \bigg|_{\ln (\ln 3)}^{\infty} $$
It's finite iff $-\alpha+1 < 0$.

If $\alpha = 1$ we have
$$\int_{\ln (\ln 3)}^{\infty}\frac{du}{u} = \ln u \bigg|_{\ln (\ln 3)}^{\infty} = +\infty.$$

Comment: What if $\alpha$ is $1$?

Comment: How is this different from mine?

Comment: @unit1991, indeed, it was better to consider $\alpha=1$ separately.

Comment: @MarkViola, firstly, you didn't change variables, so it may be a little bit harder for beginners; secondly, you didn't mention, that unit1991 almost solved the problem.

Comment: @BotnakovN. I gave a substantive HINT.  Do you see the header "HINT?"The user should be able to fill in the blanks.

Comment: @MarkViola, OK, and I emphasized that he almost solved the problem by himself and helped to solve by his way. Аre you trying to deny it?)

Comment: @BotnakovN. I don't see how your post is significantly different from mine.  Your reasons don't seem to be relevant to me.

Comment: @MarkViola, one post ignores the progress of the author of the question, who almost solved everything on his own, the other does not. Your desire to ignore this doesn't seem to be relevant to me.

Comment: @BotnakovN. It is a HINT!!!!!!

Comment: @MarkViola, OK, it was a hint, nobody denies it. And first you ask me what is the difference between two posts, and then you are surprised I answered your question)